# Calculate the first date of a pay cycle based on odd/even weeks

Tags: php, date, datetime

We are creating a pretty generic ordering system, which bases payouts to users on the current week of a pay cycle.

Our pay cycles are bi-weekly, so we consider that WEEK 1 will be an ODD week, and WEEK 2 will be an EVEN week.

- Week 1 (odd)  [start period A]
- Week 2 (even) [end period A]
- Week 3 (odd)  [start period B]
- Week 4 (even) [end period B] [Payout period A on Friday of this week]
- Week 5 (odd)  [start period C]
- Week 6 (even) [end period C] [Payout period B on Friday of this week]

And so forth.

---

We can use the following to determine whether or not it is an odd or even week:

```
    self::$now = new DateTime();
    if (self::$now->format('W') % 2 === 0) {
        // Week is even -
    } else {
        // Week is odd
    }
```

If it is an odd week, we want to take the Sunday of that week to use that as the 'Start Date' of the current pay cycle. On the other hand, if it is an even week, we want to take the Saturday of that week and use that as the 'End Date' of the current pay cycle.

Previously, our method of calculating these start and end dates was rather crude. We merely selected an arbitrary date to use as the first date of the two week pay cycle, and would use some messy `DateTime()` code to calculate diffs and so forth. We do not want to do it this way, but instead rely on whether or not the week is EVEN or ODD.

Here is the code we were using to calculate the previous start and end dates:

```php
public function getPreviousPeriodStart() {

    $daysIntoCurrentPeriod      = ((int)self::$now->diff(self::$refStart)->format('%a') % self::PERIOD_LENGTH);

    self::$prevPeriodStart      = new DateTime('2 weeks ago');
    self::$prevPeriodStart->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$daysIntoCurrentPeriod.'D'));

    return self::$prevPeriodStart;

}

public function getPreviousPeriodEnd() {

    $daysLeftCurrentPeriod      = self::PERIOD_LENGTH - ((int)self::$now->diff(self::$refStart)->format('%a') % self::PERIOD_LENGTH) - 1;

    self::$prevPeriodStart      = new DateTime('2 weeks ago');
    self::$prevPeriodStart->add(new DateInterval('P'.$daysLeftCurrentPeriod.'D'));

    return (self::$prevPeriodStart);

}
```

Again, i know this is poor and sloppy, which is why I want to improve it!

Once we have established the start and end dates of the current pay cycle, we would like to be able to determine the following values:

- current pay period start
- current pay period end
- previous pay period start
- previous pay period end
- previous period pay date (this will be the pay date for the PREVIOUS pay period - the one that ended before the current pay period began) **[This will occur the Friday of the following EVEN pay period]**
- current period pay date (this will be the pay date for the current pay period) **[This will occur the Friday of the NEXT EVEN pay period]**

I am trying to find the cleanest, sanest way to handle this. If this approach or methodology is not ideal, I would welcome any alternate suggestions - I just want to make sure this is accurate and maintainable!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you look at my post, you will see the part that says 'We would like to be able to determine the following values' : current pp start, end, previous pp start, end, etc. I want to do it in a different manner than we are doing it now, by using the ODD/EVEN approach instead of a fixed reference date.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Sorry. I was confused. In that case, check out this link http://derickrethans.nl/iso-8601-weeks.html and try getting the current week number and using it to find the beginning/ending of that week by converting a string like "2013-WXX-7", where XX is the current week. However you should be aware that ISO8601 weeks start on Monday not Sunday, so you'll have to adjust for that as well.

Comment: also look at the Carbon php library, which has a great many very useful date & time functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, **odd/even approach will fail on years that have odd number of weeks**, like year 2015, which has 53 weeks. So last week of the year 2015 will be odd, and then next week (first week in year 2016) will also be odd. Probably this is not intended?

Your first approach was better. **Choose one date as a reference, and that reference is an odd start period date.** Based on that, you now know if your current period is odd or even, see method `isOdd()` bellow.

*Example:*

```php
class DateTimeExtended extends DateTime {

    # ref start date is odd
    const REF_START = '2013-W43-1';

    protected function isOdd(DateTime $dt)
    {
        $ref = new DateTime(self::REF_START);
        return floor($dt->diff($ref)->days / 7) % 2 == 0;
    }

    public function getCurrentPeriodStart()
    {
        $dt = new DateTime($this->format('o-\WW-1'));
        if (!$this->isOdd($dt)) {
            $dt->modify('-1 week');
        }
        return $dt;
    }

    public function getCurrentPeriodEnd()
    {
        $dt = new DateTime($this->format('o-\WW-7'));
        if ($this->isOdd($dt)) {
            $dt->modify('+1 week');
        }
        return $dt;
    }

    public function getPreviousPeriodStart()
    {
        $dt = $this->getCurrentPeriodStart();
        return $dt->modify('-2 week');
    }

    public function getPreviousPeriodEnd()
    {
        $dt = $this->getCurrentPeriodEnd();
        return $dt->modify('-2 week');
    }

}
```

*Use ([demo](https://eval.in/57697)):*

```php
$dt = new DateTimeExtended;

print_r( $dt->getCurrentPeriodStart() );   # 2013-10-21
print_r( $dt->getCurrentPeriodEnd() );     # 2013-11-03
print_r( $dt->getPreviousPeriodStart() );  # 2013-10-07
print_r( $dt->getPreviousPeriodEnd() );    # 2013-10-20
```

Like [Dwayne Towell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624998/dwayne-towell) already said in the question comment, ISO8601 weeks start on Monday, not Sunday, so you will need to adjust code to make it work like that. Just replace ISO formats, like [this](https://eval.in/57698).

Comment: Greetings. I know it has been many years but, what would need to change in this code for it to work for 2017? Or any subsequent years? How can I make this code work for with the REF_START = 2017?

Comment: @Vini: just enter your own ref date?

Comment: I noticed there’s some sort of formatting on the input.

Comment: @Vini: it is a standard ISO8601 format. For your REF date you can use any known format that DateTime consumes.